# Square of difference of two disjointly supported function

Tags: functions, inequality

Let $[n]$ denotes the set $\{1,\cdots,n\}$ and $k\geq 1$ be an integer. For a function $g:[n]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, let $supp(g) = \{i\in[n]: g(i) \neq 0\}$ be the support of $g$.

Let $f_1,\cdots,f_k:[n]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be pairwise disjointly supported functions, i.e. $supp(f_i)\cap supp(f_j)=\emptyset$ whenever $i\neq j$. Let $f:[n]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function defined as $f(l) = \sum_{i=1}^k f_i(l)$ for every $1\leq l\leq n$. Prove that

> $\vert f(l)-f(m)\vert^2 \leq 2\sum_{i=1}^k\vert f_i(l)-f_i(m)\vert^2$.

This inequality seems quite trivial(although I dont have a proof). Suppose $l\in supp(f_i)$ and $m\in supp(f_j)$ for some $i\neq j$. Then the LHS is equal to $\vert f_i(l)-f_j(m)\vert^2$, but I am not sure if this is useful(perhaps is case analysis).

Any help should be welcome.

Answer (score 0):

There exist $u,v\in[k]$ (not unique if $l$ or $m$ belongs to none of the supports of the $f_i$'s) such that
$$(\forall i\ne u)\;f_i(l)=0\quad\text{and}\quad(\forall i\ne v)\;f_i(m)=0.$$ Let
$$a:=f(l)=f_u(l),\quad b:=f(m)=f_v(m).$$
Then,
$$\vert f(l)-f(m)\vert^2=(a-b)^2$$
and
$$2\sum_{i=1}^k\vert f_i(l)-f_i(m)\vert^2=\begin{cases}2(a-b)^2&\text{if }u=v\\2(a^2+b^2)&\text{if }u\ne v.
\end{cases}$$
In both cases, the inequality is now clear.

Comment: In the first line you meant $u,v\in[k]$?

Comment: Yes, thank you, updated.